# Using Android Calendar to get the current time

Tags: java, android, date, time, android-calendar

I'm trying to get the current time (HH:MM:SEC:MILLISEC) in an android app. I'm using this piece of code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int time_start = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

"Field number for get and set indicating the minute within the hour. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the MILLI is 250."

I've looked through the other methods, but I couldn't find anything specifying it would output everything. Is there anyway I can get H:M:Sec:MilliSec? or do I just have to do something like

```
c.get(Calendar.HOUR).get(Calendar.MINUTE).get(Calendar.SECOND).get(Calendar.MILLISECOND).
```

Answer (score 19):

You could try with `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");`

Like this perhaps:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String test = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
Log.e("TEST", test);
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer I was looking for. You're a legend!

Comment: @daveogrady, I am glad the answer was of help. :-)

Answer (score 9):

What about this?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:S");
String result = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go the `System.currentTimeMillis()` or the `new Date()` way, and put these in a [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), to get exactly the output you like